# ElasticSearch LockObtainFailedException on restoring index from s3 repository

Tags: java, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I keep getting the following exception on trying to restore a snapshot using cloud_aws plugin from s3 repository:

```
 [WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Landslide] [index_name][0] received shard failed for target shard [[index_name][0], node[U2w_femBQYO3f5TuOI5daw], [P], v[109], restoring[elasticsearch:backup_name], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=gJBMpmcVT6G132-h1ONGgw], unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2016-09-01T13:01:53.147Z], details[failed to create shard, failure ElasticsearchException[failed to create shard]; nested: LockObtainFailedException[Can't lock shard [index_name][0], timed out after 5000ms]; ]]], indexUUID [7quZdjJqRRmhzr7WBXqlgQ], message [failed to create shard], failure [ElasticsearchException[failed to create shard]; nested: LockObtainFailedException[Can't lock shard [index_name][0], timed out after 5000ms]; ]
[index_name][[index_name][0]] ElasticsearchException[failed to create shard]; nested: LockObtainFailedException[Can't lock shard [index_name][0], timed out after 5000ms];
    at org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.createShard(IndexService.java:389)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.applyInitializingShard(IndicesClusterStateService.java:601)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.applyNewOrUpdatedShards(IndicesClusterStateService.java:501)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.clusterChanged(IndicesClusterStateService.java:166)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService.runTasksForExecutor(InternalClusterService.java:610)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:772)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:231)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Can't lock shard [index_name][0], timed out after 5000ms
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment$InternalShardLock.acquire(NodeEnvironment.java:609)
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.shardLock(NodeEnvironment.java:537)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.createShard(IndexService.java:306)
    ... 10 more
```

ES version 2.4.0.
There's no other operation going on on elastic server. Also note that the restore operation does complete inspite of the above exception, but it takes very long to restore a < 1GB index on a 5-6 Mbps internet. Any suggestions?

EDIT: It seems its a problem with s3 buckets. Finding no particular solution to this, i have moved on to FS repository. 
i'd still be interested in the solution to this problem